# Showing HTML block on click of the preview image?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to show the HTML block on the click of Preview image.For this i used jquery image gallery.which works like to click on a image and show the full image but i want to show the HTML block instead of full image.

The gallary works like this:

```
<a href="full.jpg"><img src="thum.png"></a>
```

and i want to use this like:

```
<a href="preview.html"><img src="preview.png"></a>
```

May be i am doing wrong in above code of line.so guys please suggest me how can i do this.
Thanks In advance.

I used this jquery image gallery [this](http://gettopup.com/)

Comment: I'm not seeing any javascript that will show/hide the images. Can you post what you have tried? Creating a http://jsfiddle.net example would be very helpful

Comment: explain more correctly..

Comment: @mark see updated question ,i used this jquery image gallery.

Comment: @yogi ,what you want to know? plz ask

Comment: @HarshalMahajan in this image gallery image is showing as pop up. So according to you what should come instead of image. explain this.

Comment: @yogi ,yes i need a HTML block in pop up instead of that pop image.

Comment: then go for that examples in third row, their is an INLINE DOM example. click on that. http://gettopup.com/

Answer (score 0):

Please use Jquery [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
Example : $('#preview-page').load('preview.html');
```

Now style your " Preview-page " layout based upon your wish. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it requires that you add some class to it. Check out the [examples](http://gettopup.com/examples). That might give you a better idea. You really should have done a bit more research before posting this though, as I found that quite quickly.

Comment: ,the kind of examples given there is all related to image but i want to show the html block in pop up instead of pop up image.

Comment: There is a link that says "Open Google" next to the two images in the examples.